# if a line passes through the center of a rectangle, how to get the length of the line that is inside the rectangle?

Tags: geometry

[image]

Suppose I have a rectangle and its four corners are P0 to P3, and P0P1 is its longer side and P2P3 is its shorter side. The 4 points are counter-clockwise.

Then I have a line passes through the center of this rectangle, it has a specific direction (you can use the angle between L and X axis as theta to describe it)

My question is, if I know the coordinate of the 4 corners and L's theta, how can I get the length of the line that is inside the rectangle?

**solution: Imagine you don't have line segments like P0P1, but lines that extend infinitely through the points. Then you could calculate the intersection point of each of the four lines with L, and take the intersection point closest to the origin, so min(intersections).**

Comment: Imagine you don't have line segments like P0P1, but lines that extend infinitely through the points. Then you could calculate the intersection point of each of the four lines with L, and take the intersection point closest to the origin, so min(intersections). Due to the symmetry, you only actually need to test two of the four sides, any two adjacent sides, e.g. P0P1 and P1P2

Answer (score 0):

Consider the coordinate system along the direction of the sides of the rectangle.
Origin of this coordinate system is center of the rectangle.

Considering unit directional vector **d** along the line `L` on this coordinate system,
in this problem, we always can use absolute values as the 2 components of **d**, so situation will be as figure below.

[image]

What we needed to know is "Which side of the rectangle does the extension of **d** intersect?"
This can be solved by looking the sign of CrossProduct( **p**, **d** ), where **p** is rectangle's corner as shown in figure.

The intersection point is (`s` * **d**), and we can solve this scale factor `s` because we know the size of rectangle.
This scale value `s` is half of the value you want to know (because **d** is unit vector).